# "ORA-12401: invalid label string: " error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to run a simple update statement in Oracle to modify an Integer field of a specific row.

```
UPDATE Mytable
SET field1 = 2
WHERE field2 = 11111;
```

But I receive this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-12401: invalid label string: 
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.NUMERIC_LABEL_TO_CHAR", line 1
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC$BU0_92924", line 1
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LBACSYS.LBAC$BU0_92924'
12401. 00000 -  "invalid label string: %s"
*Cause:    The policy could not convert the label string to a valid
           internal label.
*Action:   Correct the syntax of the label string.
```

Google search did not bring much results. Do you have any idea about the solution of this error?

Comment: I am guessing, but from the error, it looks like one or both of your fields are declared as a "char" type, but you are attempting to reference them as numeric types. Please provide the table definition.

Comment: Are you familiar with "triggers"? The error message shows pretty clearly that the error occurred during the execution of a trigger - which means you have a trigger on your table, which fired when you executed the `update` statement. The error occurred during the execution of the trigger, so to help you debug this, you would need to share the code of the trigger.